# Error in `purrr::map()`, unable to use step_select_*() from colino and workflow_map() together

Tags: r, purrr, tidymodels

Trying to use different step_select functions from the colino package before fitting multiple models with workflow_set(). Apparently using a step_select function as preprocessing in the recipe make it impossible to use worflow_map() after. The exact same error occurs wwhen uding tune_grid(), with a workflow including a step_select_*() function.

I also inspected the error report, and I was not able to identify what tibble is concerned by the error.

Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 2.
Caused by error in `tibble()`:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 2: Existing data.
• Size 3: Column `call_info`.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

```
library(parsnip)
library(dplyr)
library(fastDummies)
library(colino)
library(workflowsets)
library(tune)

data(iris)

logit_model <- logistic_reg(engine = "glm")

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") 

iris_cv <- vfold_cv(iris2)

recipe <- recipe(Species ~ ., data = iris2) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_select_vip(all_predictors(), model = logit_model,
                  threshold = 0.9, outcome = "Species") %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

logit_vip2 <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(rec = recipe),
    models = list(logit = logistic_reg(engine = "glm")),
    cross = TRUE) 

res_logit_vip2 <- 
  logit_vip2 %>% 
  workflow_map(fn = "tune_grid", resamples =iris_cv,
               verbose = TRUE, control =control_grid(verbose =TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was corrected by the author of the package, it sholdn't be a problem anymore. [see](https://github.com/stevenpawley/colino/issues/1)